# Detecting 5V output from USB charger via Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb

How can the presence of a 5V output from a USB charger be detected using a Raspberry Pi?

**Scenario:** My Raspberry Pi is powered by a (USB) powerbank which is continuously being charged by a dual-port (USB) wall-charger plugged into the mains [this setup serves as a mini-UPS for the Pi].
One port of that wall charger supplies the powerbank, while the other is unused.

**Problem:** I would like to detect when the mains supply is off, using the Pi.

**Potential solution:** Since one of the 5V outputs on the wall-charger are unused, maybe I can interface that to the GPIO pins on the Pi to let it know when the mains is off.
I know that the Pi's GPIO runs off 3.3V logic, so I assume a simple voltage-divider like [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=22841) will be required.
Are there additional precautions that need to be taken? Any other suggestions to achieve the same goal?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I came across this http://raspi-ups.appspot.com/en/hardware.jsp which might give you some ideas

Comment: @SteveRobillard: Thanks for sharing that. I'd come across it earlier when looking into a UPS for the Pi. However, the LAN port on my Pi is being used rendering this particular solution not applicable.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in tapping off from the 5V output.  I would choose a resistor divider which gave about 3.3V if the input was say 8V (it should still be seen as high if the output is 5V).  That would give some protection from (unlikely) rogue voltages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple voltage divider will "work". But how much do you trust your charger, and how much do you value your Pi?

A capacitor in parallel with <strike>either</strike> resistor helps to the stabilize the sensed voltage, which protects from short voltage spikes. (A capacitor across the upper resistor will in fact **INCREASE** the transient voltage - if you must do this connect to Ground.)

For longer surges, a Zener diode can give extra protection. But to prevent it from frying as well, you will need a fuse. I.e. if your Zener limits the input to 5.6V and can dissipate 1W, your fuse should be rated at 178 mA.

Comment: Thanks. I have noted to add a capacitor in parallel to one of the resistors. How should a Zener diode be placed [in relation to the simple voltage divider circuit]? Reverse-biased in parallel to the second resistor?
Also, [this](http://www.zendure.com/products/3-4a-dual-port-wall-charger) is the charger I'm using by Zendure.

Comment: A 5.6 V Zener isn't going to protect you when you put in in parallel with a resistor that should be at 3.3 V ! No, such a Zener protects you from a source exceeding 5.6V. An excess voltage causes a significant current to run through the Zener, not through your Pi, at which point to fuse (which is closest to the input ) blows to isolate everything.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So a 5.6V Zener diode in parallel with the entire circuit? With a 178 mA fuse in series with that Zener?

Comment: @Abhi: Yes, but you're unlikely to find a 178 mA fuse, and besides, you hardly need any current anyway (1mA is sufficient). It was an upper limit based on a hypothetical 1W Zener. On a more general note: if it becomes too complex for you, do remember that the Pi isn't the most expensive device.

Comment: Got it. It seems hard to find that small a fuse anyway so I'll just let the Zener diode burn out instead. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Abhi: That won't work like you think it does, you can't abuse the Zener as a makeshift fuse. A fuse needs to be in series, and the Zener is in parallel. _If_ the Zener fries, the Pi also fries. But don't worry too much; it's a risk you can probably afford to take.

Comment: Whoops, I'm making too many silly mistakes. I understand why that won't work now that I drew it out. I understand it may not be possible to get a low-voltage (5V) low-amp fuse. It seems at this point I'll just trust the USB charger to have sufficient in-built protection. Thanks very much for your help.